# simple query is not using indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log, query-performance

1. My query is not using indexes.
2. it was taking around 5 seconds.
3. output is 500 rows only. it is a simple query

Please find the explain plan and table structure here.

Explain Plan

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found`
               FROM `builds` AS `build`
               WHERE (`user_id` = '32762'
               AND `country_id` = 'gb'
               AND `share` = 0
               AND `mode` = 'bouquet'
               AND `build_data` != '');

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | build | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 35209 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table structure

```
mysql> show create table builds\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: builds
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `builds` (
  `build_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `derivation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `share` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `build_data` text NOT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`build_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please don't make people guess what indexes you have. If you've got a query that's not using indexes, providing those index definitions is rather capital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your table structure, you only have a `PRIMARY KEY` on `build_id`.

Thus, there *is no* index that can be utilized to solve this query. I suspect you are very new to indexes; having an index on some column doesn't mean all queries will run faster. You need an index that matches you query.

For example, in your case, an index on `user_id` or an index on `country_id` or an index on `share` or an index on `mode` would work; Indexes on combinations of the above, like `INDEX (user_id, country_id)` would do well, too.

Which should you choose? One that would significantly limit the number of rows to "search by hand" (so to speak), and one that would do well for your other common queries.

My recommendation to you is to study how indexes work in relational databases.